# Code is working in jsfiddle, but not working in my website

Tags: jquery

Please help me to fix this.

I have a link with the code http://jsfiddle.net/vop50rct/ its working fine in jsfiddle, but if i put the same thing in localhost its not working any specific reason? i also checked javascripts and jquery everything is embedded correctly (other jsfiddle code works fine).

can anyone guide me on how to place this code.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Page</title>  
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

jQuery:

```
_mouseDrag: function(event) {
    var self = this;
    this.dragged = true;

    if (this.options.disabled)
      return;

    var options = this.options;

    var x1 = this.opos[0], y1 = this.opos[1], x2 = event.pageX, y2 = event.pageY;
    if (x1 > x2) { var tmp = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = tmp; }
    if (y1 > y2) { var tmp = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = tmp; }
    this.helper.css({left: x1, top: y1, width: x2-x1, height: y2-y1});

    this._trigger("drag", event);

    return false;
},
```

Comment: What exactly don't work?

Comment: Do you have any error in your console?

Comment: jquery/1.3.2.. Are you sure the jQuery versions match?

Comment: I have no error for console time, it's execute successfully. but mouse drag event is not working.  and also jQuery version is match.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.

i put in all jQuery code in to document.ready function.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
do your code here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you embed your JQuery code into you HTML file? From your HTML fragment I can see that you load only JQuery related scripts, but you JQuery code is not executed anywhere.

You can browse to your jsfiddle sample and have a look how the final code (in the result frame) is assembled.

Comment: Thanks for your response..  Please check http://jsfiddle.net/vop50rct/ link, I used same code for that. In jsfiddle it's working fine but not working in my site.

Comment: I have copied the generated source from the result frame in jsfiddle and pasted it to separate file demo.html. When I one demo.html in Chrome, it works.